# Animations with Plotly with two parameters

Tags: python, animation, plotly

With Plotly it is possible to easily create animations using animation_frame` parameter in Plotly Express, documented [here](https://plotly.com/python/animations/). I would like to do the same but with two parameters (or more eventually). Adding pseudo-code to the example they provide in the link I posted, I would like to do something like:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder()
px.scatter(df, 
    x = "gdpPercap", 
    y = "lifeExp", 
    animation_frame_1 = "year", 
    animation_frame_2 = "another parameter"
)
```

and obtain as a result this plot:

[image]

Is this possible? How? I am not interested in the animation feature (i.e. the automatic sweeping of the parameters with time), only in having the sliders to explore the data.

Answer (score 1):

- concept

  1. use **plotly express** to create a figure for each *animation frame*
  2. build up all frames from step 1
  3. build up layout, primarily **sliders** from figures in step 1
  4. finally build a new figure from steps 2 & 3
- limitations

  1. space... sliders that a lot of space
  2. each slider is independent,  last selected slider is what is shown.  No visual cue

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = px.data.gapminder()
# add another column to "animate" on...
df["decade-continent"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: f'{round(x["year"], -1)}-{x["continent"]}', axis=1
)

# use px to do heavy lifting construction
figs = [
    px.scatter(
        df,
        x="gdpPercap",
        y="lifeExp",
        animation_frame=ac,
    )
    # columns that become sliders
    for ac in ["continent", "year", "decade-continent"]
]

# extract frames and sliders from each of the animated figures
layout = figs[0].to_dict()["layout"]
layout.pop("updatemenus") # don't want play and pause buttons
layout["sliders"] = []
frames = []
for i, f in enumerate(figs):
    slider = f.to_dict()["layout"]["sliders"]
    slider[0]["y"] = -0.6 * i
    slider[0]["x"] = 0
    slider[0]["len"] = 1

    layout["sliders"] += slider
    frames += f.frames

# finally build the figure with multiple sliders
go.Figure(data=figs[0].data, frames=frames, layout=layout).update_layout(
    margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0}, height=400
)
```

[image]